# AngularJS v.1 : Table with different answers per line but having to merge in different column

Tags: mysql, angularjs

My problem is that I get data with "ng-repeat" in my table but some lines contain more answers than others.

[image: The table I had]

So I'd like to make a table that is formatted to look like the one below.

[image: The table I want]

Here is my html code currently that allows me to get the first table that is not very orderly:

```
<table id="fileAttenteTable" ng-init="displayData()">
    <tr>
        <th>Patients</th>
        <th>Priorité (ATS)</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="patient in patients | filter: { priorite :'1'}">{{ patient.prenom }}</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="patient in patients | filter: { priorite :'2'}">{{ patient.prenom }}</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="patient in patients | filter: { priorite :'3'}">{{ patient.prenom }}</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="patient in patients | filter: { priorite :'4'}">{{ patient.prenom }}</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="patient in patients | filter: { priorite :'5'}">{{ patient.prenom }}</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my JS who send me my data correctly :

```
app.controller('fileAttenteCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, user, patientService) {

    $scope.displayData = function () {
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/patients',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            },

        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.patients = response.data;
            console.log($scope.patients);

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
});
```

Here is my JSOn response. This is an array of Object. I just let one for example :

[{"idpatient":2,"nom":"Dousse","prenom":"Donald","dateNaissance":"2017-06-07T00:00:00.000Z","nomAccompagnant":"Dousse","prenomAccompagnant":"Patricia","autoriteParental":1,"mobile":3456789,"priorite":"3","animal":null,"codeQR":null,"heureArrivee":"2017-06-30T10:12:06.000Z","heureLiberation":null,"traitement":"Attente"}, {nextObject}]

And the list of object is like this :

[image]

Comment: Post your JSON response.

Comment: I updated my post with my JSOn response